# Oracle Form 12c field showing hash instesad of number

Tags: oracle, hash, key, commit, oracleforms

I am working on Oracle forms 12c and facing an issue with few fields showing as hash(####) values instead of number field on data block when saving changes by clicking on SAVE (commit) button.

Also showing below error
(FRM-40735 KEY COMMIT Trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-01483)
it seems that it is due to change of field item from number to HASH (string)

For further information:-

-Fields are database items

-Trying to insert value in database fields by entering value on field.

-Size of fields are more than entered number value.

-on re-querying data block using (f7 & f8) data is showing correctly as number.

-Not able to recreate this issue on different database(working fine on other   database)

is it something related to environment issue or minor bug while coding?

Comment: what do you see for `format mask` properties of those hashed fields?

Comment: format mask is not specified for these fields.

Answer (score 0):

If the Returning_Dml_value property on datablock is set to Yes,it sometimes causes junk values to be populated and asks a requery on block. Try setting it to No instead.I faced a similar issue once and it got resolved by setting Returning_Dml_value property to No.
The following blog explains more about this property of Oracle forms:
 http://cave-geek.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: Hi Neeraj,Thanks for the input.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this has been very use full to resolve the issue.  i have tried to change the DML_property as 'No' and it has resolved the issue of showing junk characters.